# Get exponent from a scientific notation

Tags: c++

How do we extract the exponent and sign from a "scientific" notation?

If we print a double value with printf("%lf  %e") it shows par ex.:

```
   normal   scientific
   ------   ----------
   -888.3   -8.88e2    
    1.23     1.23e0    
    3.001    3.1e-1
```

The solution pointed in [How to get Exponent of Scientific Notation in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471031/how-to-get-exponent-of-scientific-notation-in-matlab)

```
x = floor(log10(N))
```

works only for positive values N. With -N it shows -nan(ind). Obviously Log10() with negatie value is not allowed.

Comment: Could you just use `abs`?

Comment: yes, but then I the sign is wrong

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685181/how-to-get-the-sign-mantissa-and-exponent-of-a-floating-point-number) what you are looking for?

Comment: No, that's not in the scientific notation

Comment: Why not just keep track of the sign with `bool neg = signbit(N);`, then reapply signed-ness after calculating `floor(log10(abs(N)))`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't care about the sign of the number, you need the *exponent only*, so you can get rid of the sign safely:

```
log10(abs(N))
```

Where `abs` returns the absolute value of `N`, which is always non-negative and thus can be used as an argument to `log10`.

Comment: I need the sign too. Ex -3 or 3 is a big difference

Comment: @TomTom, my answer is about removing the sign of _the number_, not the exponent.